# How to make the form editor faster?

Tags: delphi, ide, cross-platform, form-designer

I was building a cross-platform GUI. Everything worked smoothly until I changed some stuff and the Form Designed got terribly slow. I did multiple operations and I don't know which exactly broke Delphi. Some of them:
   Switching Style between Windows and other platforms.
   Switching View between master and OSX, etc.
   Adding StyleBook to the form.
   Others

Moving/resizing a control with ctrl+arrows takes one second per pixel!

Any idea how to repair the IDE?

---

Update:

Deleting the StyleBook didn't help.
However, after removing the MainForm.iPhone.fmx, MainForm.Macintosh.fmx, MainForm.Surface.fmx, etc helped. So, the bug appeared after I switched the view. This is when those files are autogenerated. Most of the speed (let's say something like 75-80%) recovered after that.

We have to figure out how to make the project work without those files. Or if we can simply delete them every time the designed gets slow. First of all I will check what kind of information does the IDE store in there.

Comment: Reinstalling IDE should help.

Comment: Since you think it is related with project, why not to create blank project and make some tests?

Comment: I started like you from the idea that it could be the IDE (I haven't used FMX a lot). Then I made some experiments and I figure out is those autogenerated FMX file that make the editor slow. But we still have a long way to find out how to fix the whole issue. Anyway, we figured out some important clues until now.

Comment: @Dima How did you diagnose that the drastic action of reinstallation would be the solution?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I believe that if one checks option *Make IDE slower* he definitely will be able to uncheck it again. So from question it is not obvious *which exactly* actions did asker to make IDE works slowly than usual, so it could take lot of time to track these actions down to understand what causes such behaving of IDE. So I suppose that reinstalling IDE will take lower amount of time to "repair" IDE.

Comment: Seems to me to be pretty unhelpful advice

Comment: Yep. But you also mentioned in question *Some of them* and *Others* which are not exact reasons caused IDE's incorrect behaviour. My first comment has been addressed to these words.

Comment: No-no-no. Don't play this game on me. Check timestamps of my first comment and *your first* question editing, where you have added *update* part. You will be surprised, don't you?

Comment: No, my comment was correct at the time it had been made. Then you say, that you  clarified possible reasons in question. I wasn't agree, because you say *some of them* and *others*. After this you were saying that you have added *Update* part in your question. But I pointed, that my *first* comment has been made *before your first edit*. Then you deleted all your previous comments, so no one will be able to understand what is going there and after all ask me to stop this. Why are you doing so?

Comment: Sorry. I really don't understand what you are talking about. Anyway, is this discussion still relevant? I propose to talk about the bug I have found in the IDE. Cool?

Comment: I like you first comment and I just up-voted it. I will consider it. Thanks for your input.